# Logging particular package in different file using log4j

Tags: log4j

I have log4j configuration like this

```
#
# Log4j properties for the CometD Server.
#
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logfile
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.xbean=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=INFO
log4j.logger.org.cometd=INFO
log4j.logger.test.cometd.server=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.googlecode=INFO

# File appender
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.file=${cometd.log.dir}/cometd.log
log4j.appender.logfile.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.logfile.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.logfile.append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz} (%t) %C#%M %L %p] - %m %n
```

I want that all logs for package "com.googlecode" goes to one file and rest all logs remain in log file (mentioned above as cometd.log)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to this and posting it for wider community who might need it later.

The key here is we need a separate appender for each file that we need and also as rootlogger is set with an appender we need to stop inheriting it

So final config will be like following

```
#
# Log4j properties for the CometD Server.
#
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logfile
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.xbean=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=INFO
log4j.logger.org.cometd=INFO
log4j.logger.test.cometd.server=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.googlecode=INFO, probleLogfile
log4j.additivity.com.googlecode=false

# File appender
log4j.appender.probleLogfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.probleLogfile.file=${cometd.log.dir}/probe.log
log4j.appender.probleLogfile.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.probleLogfile.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.probleLogfile.append=true
log4j.appender.probleLogfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.probleLogfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz} (%t) %C#%M %L %p] - %m %n


log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.file=${cometd.log.dir}/cometd.log
log4j.appender.logfile.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.logfile.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.logfile.append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz} (%t) %C#%M %L %p] - %m %n
```

So by specifying  `log4j.additivity.com.googlecode=false` we have stop inheriting from root logger for this class and its children.

and we have specified a separate appender for this to keep its log in other file.